# Use font for listings different from the main text

Tags: listings, typefaces

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
We use the \lstinline[language=sh]|mycommand| as follows:
\begin{lstlisting}[language=sh]
  mycommand arg1 arg2
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

The problem is that mycommand is typefaced in the same font as the main text. I would like it to stand out from the text in `\lstinline` and be of the same font as in the environment `lstlisting`. How to achieve this effect?

An experiment with adding `basicstyle==\ttfamily`:

```
We use the \lstinline[language=sh, basicstyle=\ttfamily]|mycommand| as follows:
\begin{lstlisting}[language=sh, basicstyle=\ttfamily]
  mycommand arg1 arg2
  echo ``Hey''
\end{lstlisting}
```

yields the following output:

[image]

Although, mycommand is now written with a different typeface, the code is listed monotonously - the different typeface for echo has disappeared.

Comment: Have a look at the basicstyle key in the listing manual

Comment: @daleif, yes it makes the listing have a different font but also monotonous using that single font.

Comment: So what do you want then?

Comment: So what is it you're asking

Comment: @daleif, I illustrated the problem of using `basicstyle=\ttfamily` in an update to the question.

Comment: That's because the cm tt font has no bold version. Try a different monospaced font

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither the default setup of `listings` nor the standard LaTeX TT font are particularly pleasant for the eye. However, this is easy to fix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}            % load a nice TT font
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily, language=sh}    % set defaults for any listing

\begin{document}
We use the \lstinline|mycommand| as follows:
\begin{lstlisting}
  mycommand arg1 arg2
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now echo is bold (see my updated question), but arg1 arg2 are of the same font as mycommand.

Comment: Apparently arg1 arg2 having a different font in the question is just an illusion

Comment: @Viesturs: `echo` is a keyword in the `sh` language, so it is typeset in `keywordstyle`, which defaults to `keywordstyle=\bfseries`. You can overwrite this in the `\lstset` options. The reason it did not appear bold on your example using the standard TT font is that this font does not provide boldface glyphs.